# Run aspnet_regsql on an SQL Server Express database in APP_DATA

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express, membership-provider

When I run the aspnet_regsql command in wizard mode, there is no way to select an SQL Sever Express database file even after specifying ".\SQLEXPRESS" in the database server name. How can I work around this?

Comment: As I remember there are shouldn't be problems with express version. Check if SQL service is running and that the username/password are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/archive/2005/09/26/425966.aspx).

This can not be done from the wizard interface. The command line parameter to do this is: 
`aspnet_regsql -A all -C "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" -d "C:\MyProject\APP_DATA\aspnetdb.mdf"`

Comment: Saved me so much hassle. I wonder why these annoyances cannot be solved easily.